# Debug-for-me/ troubleshoot duplicates. What is there to do to help?

Tags: discussion

**I love stack overflow..**

But it seems as there is a daily stream of questions that are related to a troubleshoot software or troubleshot a line of code. Right now I'm facing an issue which I believe is caused by Eclipse and all I can find is this [set of question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612642/r-cannot-be-resolved-android)  in SO over and over, no need to cite any just search for the same keywords.

**these questions..**

Get answered so fast and the upvotes for both question and answer come so fast that it looks like they stack up for good.

In this specific example, you can count on Eclipse build problem eternally, thus these questions (which all have the same answer) will keep comming.

I've been flagging some as duplicates but nothing has happened. Maybe there is one more thing we users can do to raise attention to this kind of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a large degree it comes down to the community members that actively follow those tags.  Do they upvote content that is a duplicate of many past posts, or do they just vote to close as a duplicate?  Some tags tend to have enough people making a pointed effort to close that they get closed quickly, and those who try to sneak in an answer tend to not get a lot of upvotes.  Other tags either don't have users trying to close, or don't have enough for questions to be closed quickly enough to prevent a flood of answers.  Some community members also are more inclined to upvote answers to such questions (thus encouraging people to answer instead of vote-close).

As for what you can do, you can:

1. Flag/vote to close questions that are duplicates.  Ensure that a link to the proposed duplicate is in the comments.  Lots of people will vote to close once someone has already found the duplicate, but won't go around searching for the duplicate to close with.
2. Not upvote answers to such questions.

It's actually rather by design that you, by yourself, can't do a whole lot.  There needs to be consensus among at least a noticeable number of people viewing these questions for them to be closed.

Comment: Thanks servy, does 'consensus' in this case mean that a few users have to flag the questions?

Comment: @quinestor "consensus" means 5 users (with at least 3k rep) need to vote to close, or at least one moderator needs to vote to close.  Flagging the question merely brings that question to the attention of high rep users and moderators.  The more the flags, the higher up it'll be in the queue of flagged content.